# many to many with extra field flask-admin sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I have a question about using the "ModelView" class.
I have 2 models that have a many to many relationship. I had to modify the intermediate table because it takes an additional element.

I have looked for several solutions but none of them work. Here are my models and what I'm trying to do to build a drop-down menu in the view.

I'm trying to get the same result as the tutorial I found on youtube: [image]

I've been looking a lot, but there's really no example and no help for this kind of relationship and display.

Here is an example of my code if you have an idea to guide me. That would be great. Thank you in advance

models.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# Create database connection object
db = SQLAlchemy()
class Cocktail(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cocktail'

    idCocktails = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    bottles = db.relationship('Bottles_has_cocktails',lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete-orphan", backref='cocktail_join')
    path = db.Column(db.String(128))



class Bottle(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bottle'
    idBottles = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    solenoidValve = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    step = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    empty = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    path = db.Column(db.String(128))
    cocktail = db.relationship('Bottles_has_cocktails', lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete-orphan", backref='bottle_join')



class Bottles_has_cocktails(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bottlesHasCocktail'
    id_bottles = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('bottle.idBottles'), primary_key=True)
    id_cocktails = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cocktail.idCocktails'), primary_key=True)
    dose = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    bottle = db.relationship(Bottle, lazy='joined')
```

views.py:

```
import os
import os.path as op
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask_admin import Admin, form
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from jinja2 import Markup
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for

from engine.models import Bottle, Cocktail, Bottles_has_cocktails, db

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
file_path = os.path.join(basedir, 'static', 'files')

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
app.config.from_object('config')

db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


#######################
# ADMINISTRATION LINES#
#######################

@listens_for(Cocktail, 'after_delete')
def del_image(mapper, connection, target):
    if target.path:
        # Delete image
        try:
            os.remove(op.join(file_path, target.path))
        except OSError:
            pass

        # Delete thumbnail
        try:
            os.remove(op.join(file_path,
                              form.thumbgen_filename(target.path)))
        except OSError:
            pass


def _list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name):
    if not model.path:
        return 'un test'

    return Markup('<img src="%s">' % url_for('static',
                                             filename='files/{}'.format(form.thumbgen_filename(model.path))))
class CocktailAdmin(sqla.ModelView):


    column_formatters = {
        'path': _list_thumbnail
    }
    # Alternative way to contribute field is to override it completely.
    # In this case, Flask-Admin won't attempt to merge various parameters for the field.
    form_extra_fields = {
        'path': form.ImageUploadField('Image',
                                      base_path=file_path,
                                      thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True),
                                      url_relative_path='files/',
                                      )
    }

class BottleAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    column_display_pk = True
    form_columns = ['name','cocktail',]


class BottleAsCocktail(sqla.ModelView):
    #column_display_pk = True
    form_columns = ['dose']


admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(CocktailAdmin(Cocktail, db.session))
admin.add_view(BottleAdmin(Bottle, db.session))
admin.add_view(BottleAsCocktail(Bottles_has_cocktails, db.session))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(host='192.168.1.81', port=5000)
```

Comment: It looks like you need [inline forms](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/tree/master/examples/sqla-custom-inline-forms) for it. There is a [question with an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637653/flask-admin-with-additional-field-in-relationship-many-to-many) with very similar model structure as in your question.

Comment: Thanks , excuse me for long time of response